# Combining multiple summary tables with subheadings

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have data with several demographic factors.

I am trying to create a publication-quality summary table like this:

```
                     N  
Sex
      M             150
      F             150
Marital Status
      Single        100
      Married       100
      Divorced      100
Age
      <25           75
      25-34         75
      35-44         75
      >= 45         75
```

I can easily generate each individual piece of this, like so:

```
    require(dplyr)

 dd <- data.frame(barcode = c("16929", "64605", "03086", "29356", "23871"),
   sex = factor(c("M", "F", "M", "F", "M")), 
   marital = factor(c("Married", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Divorced")),
   age_group = factor(c("<25", "25-34", "35-44", "45-54", ">= 55")))

require(dplyr)

age_groups <- dd %>% group_by(age_group) %>% count()
sex <- dd %>% group_by(sex) %>% count()
marital <- dd %>% group_by(marital) %>% count()
```

And I can create individual RMarkdown tables for each of them with any of several solutions, like `kable` or `pander`.

```
require(knitr)
kable(age_groups)
kable(sex)
kable(marital)
```

But I can't find a way to combine them as parts of a single table with a subheading for each category. The separate tables have different column widths and aligning them by hand and inserting intervening subheading rows (in raw LaTeX?) seems like a bad solution.

This is a very common reporting format-- the standard Table 1 for many journal articles-- and I would like to find a general solution to creating it.

Comment: My usual solution is to put these values into a matrix with the row and column names fitting what I want in the table and NA values where I want spaces. I then use `xtable` from the package with the same name to construct a Latex table. There are SO posts on how to get it to span multiple rows, but it can be a little tricky to get working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(expss)
library(knitr)
dd = data.frame(barcode = c("16929", "64605", "03086", "29356", "23871"),
                 sex = factor(c("M", "F", "M", "F", "M")), 
                 marital = factor(c("Married", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Divorced")),
                 age_group = factor(c("<25", "25-34", "35-44", "45-54", ">= 55"), 
                                    levels = c("<25", "25-34", "35-44", "45-54", ">= 55")))


dd %>% tab_cells("Sex" = sex, "Marital status" = marital, "Age" = age_group) %>% 
    tab_cols(total(label = "N")) %>% 
    tab_stat_cases(total_row_position = "none") %>% 
    tab_pivot()
```

Above code produces output as in your example but work only for HTML output.
Second code snippet works for all knitr formats but output slightly differs from your example.

```
dd %>% tab_cells("Sex" = sex, "Marital status" = marital, "Age" = age_group) %>% 
    tab_cols(total(label = "N")) %>% 
    tab_stat_cases(total_row_position = "none") %>% 
    tab_pivot() %>% 
    split_columns() %>% 
    kable()
```

First output:

[image]

Second output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem and after fiddling around adding empty rows with the group labels I stumbled upon the kableExtra::group_rows option.

This way you can group some of the rows of your table and give them a label.

Just adding these answer here because I found this question three years later and maybe someone can benefit.

```
require(dplyr)

dd <- data.frame(barcode = c("16929", "64605", "03086", "29356", "23871"),
                 sex = factor(c("M", "F", "M", "F", "M")), 
                 marital = factor(c("Married", "Single", "Single", "Single", "Divorced")),
                 age_group = factor(c("<25", "25-34", "35-44", "45-54", ">= 55")))

require(dplyr)

age_groups <- dd %>%
  group_by(age_group) %>%
  count() %>% 
  rename(variable = age_group) %>% 
  ungroup

sex <- dd %>% 
  group_by(sex) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  rename(variable = sex)%>% 
  ungroup

marital <- dd %>% 
  group_by(marital) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  rename(variable = marital)%>% 
  ungroup

freq_table <- age_groups %>% 
  add_row(sex) %>% 
  add_row(marital)

knitr::kable(freq_table) %>% 
  kableExtra::group_rows(group_label = "Age groups", start_row = 1, end_row = 5) %>% 
  kableExtra::group_rows(group_label = "Sex", start_row = 6, end_row = 7) %>% 
  kableExtra::group_rows(group_label = "Marital status", start_row = 8, end_row = 10)
```

[Short table with group labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5a1i.jpg)

Unfortunately I can't add the image directly in here, as I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite a complete solution, but a good place to start may be the [pander](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/) package.

```
library(pander)
pander(list(`Age groups` = age_groups, `Sex` = sex, `Marital` = marital))
# 
# 
#   * **Age groups**:
# 
#     ---------------
#      age_group   n
#     ----------- ---
#         <25      1
# 
#        >= 55     1
# 
#        25-34     1
# 
#        35-44     1
# 
#        45-54     1
#     ---------------
# 
#   * **Sex**:
# 
#     ---------
#      sex   n
#     ----- ---
#       F    2
# 
#       M    3
#     ---------
# 
#   * **Marital**:
# 
#     --------------
#      marital    n
#     ---------- ---
#      Divorced   1
# 
#      Married    1
# 
#       Single    3
#     --------------
# 
# 
# <!-- end of list -->
# 
#
```